# Summary statistics display in the front end dashboard

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I wanted to inquire, i am using dash,  how to display a value computed from the back end? say I am going to show the sum (in the front end) of the `Sales` column from a dataframe `df` in the backend, so, how should i set up the dashboard?

i understand i will have the line below for the output,

```
html.Div(id='sum')
```

but how do i set the callback?

```
@app.callback(Output('sum', 'children'), 
                     [Input('df', 'value')])
     def get_sum('Sales'):
         sum = df["Sales"].sum
         return 'Grand Total = "{}"'.format(sum)
```

thank you guys!
by the way, i read this too,
[How to get the count from a dataframe from a Dash Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989212/how-to-get-the-count-from-a-dataframe-from-a-dash-callback)
but the input was a drop down, mine is no value input needed, i only need to show the value of the statistics summary each time i open the dashboard.

my desired result is as follow,
[image]

The dollar sign is my html.Img; 
the Total Annual Revenue is my html.H1;
while the 45.7M is the location I want my statistics in.

Comment: Do you mind to provide as [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: To clarify: do you want to print just the sum or your dashboard cointains plots too?

Comment: thank you @rpanai, i have edited my question, and you are right, my dashboard has other plots too.

Comment: Question: if there is no callbacks (as dropdowns) do you really need a dashboard? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: i found the answer myself, thank you @rpanai! the answer is easy, i only need to make another html.H1 for that.

Comment: If you like post the answer.

Comment: sure, i love this community. I don't need any callback, i only have to put the forexample, html.Div(df["Sales"].sum)